# How would I constantly update a string in xamarin Using MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Making a clock that counts down to a persons death

i have thread that checks the time and then figures out how many weeks are left then displays them.

i thought id do this by using ViewModel.TimeLeftString = TimeLeft.ToString()

View

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Title" Text="{Binding TimeLeft}" BackgroundColor="Purple"/>
```

View Model

```
string timeLeft;

        public string TimeLeft
        {
            get => timeLeft;
            set
            {
                timeLeft = value;

                var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(TimeLeft));

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }
```

Model (this is being ran in a thread)

```
DateTime LastRecordedTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            while (true)
            {
                //read current time,
                DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;


                if (CurrentTime >= LastRecordedTime)
                {
                    LastRecordedTime = addInterval(CurrentTime, Interval, DurationOfInterval);
                    Console.WriteLine($"time has passed {LastRecordedTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy |                 HH:mm:ss")}");

                    //run the funkin program thing
                    ViewModel.TimeSpent = CurrentTime.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(CurrentTime.ToString());




                }
            }
```

This doesn't work though and displays nothing. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You are just going to have a loop that spins?  You don't want to use a timer or a call to `await Task.Delay` or something?  Your loop is going to soak up all of the machine cycles, probably starving the UI.

Comment: use a `Timer`, not `while(true)`

Comment: okay thank you jason will do that. any clue for how to go about displaying the time properly

Comment: there are numerous examples of building countdown timers with XF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description you posted,I created a simple demo and achieved a similar function.

You can refer to the following code:

1.create a viewmodel (`MyViewModel.cs`) and implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

I also added `Device.StartTimer` to the constructor of the viewmodel to change the value of `TimeLeft`.Once changing the value of `TimeLeft`, the UI will update automatically.

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {

        string timeLeft;
        public string TimeLeft
        {
            set { SetProperty(ref timeLeft, value); }
            get { return timeLeft; }
        }
  
        public MyViewModel()
        {

            TimeLeft = "2023.5.18";


            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () => {

                DateTime LastRecordedTime = DateTime.MinValue;

                DateTime CurrentTime = DateTime.Now;

                if (CurrentTime >= LastRecordedTime)
                {
                    //LastRecordedTime = addInterval(CurrentTime, Interval, DurationOfInterval);
                    Console.WriteLine($"time has passed {LastRecordedTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy |HH:mm:ss")}");

                    //run the funkin program thing
                    TimeLeft = CurrentTime.ToString();
                }

                return true;

            });
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

2.`MainPage.xaml`

Here set the `BindingContext` for the page and bind `TimeLeft` to a Label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:mvvmapp518="clr-namespace:MVVMApp518"
             x:Class="MVVMApp518.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <mvvmapp518:MyViewModel></mvvmapp518:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>
        <Label  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Title" Text="{Binding TimeLeft}" />

        
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

> ViewModel.TimeSpent = CurrentTime.ToString();

From the code you shared, I couldn't find the code that you changed the value of `TimeLeft`.

Besides,we also need to make sure to modify the same instance of class `MyViewModel` which is the `BindingContext` of your page.

Comment: I realised my error. i got MVVM all wrong though the Model was the code behind. didn't realise the view model was the code behind. I'm so sorry to have wasted all these peoples time for my big stupid brain. thank you for taking the time though i have become slightly less stupid because of you. I owe you that

Comment: @keenan Neither the Model nor the ViewModel are the code-behind! The code-behind is the *.xaml.cs* file of a View.

Comment: @exerspej ahh, it seems i don't have a clue then. thank for the help